# Detecting SVG image in PHP

Tags: php, image, svg

Using PHP, I'd like to check if a uploaded image is in jpg, gif, png, or svg format.  I found exif_imagetype function could check the file format, but it does not support svg format.  Is there any way to detect svg format in PHP?

Comment: Svg may not be seen as an image file. It's an XML based markup language.

Answer (score 13):

To extend Victors answer, you can use `mime_content_type('/path/to/file');` (see [php.net manual for the function](http://php.net/mime_content_type)) and check if the return string is equal to `image/svg+xml`. Something like:

```
public function isSvg($filePath = '/path/to/file')
{
    return 'image/svg+xml' === mime_content_type($filePath);
}
```

Comment: Beware that certain SVG files will be decoded as MIME `image/svg+xml` whilst others will have just `image/svg` (w/o XML part). This is due to declaration and export by various tools out there. So I check SVG with both: ```$mimeType = mime_content_type($filePath);
    return preg_match("/SVG/i", $mimeType);```

Answer (score 7):

```
mime_content_type(realpath('img/logo.svg'));
```

return `"image/svg+xml"`.
Your svg file must contain `<xml>` tag at first line as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46366819, something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
mime_content_type($filePath);
```

Be careful if svg file is startting from `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="210" height="80">`
i'm getting "text/html"

Answer (score 0):

My method

```
 if($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/svg+xml'){

     $xmlget = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
     $xmlattributes = $xmlget->attributes();
     $width = (string) $xmlattributes->width;  $width=preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $width); 
     $height = (string) $xmlattributes->height; $height=preg_replace('/[^\d]+/', '', $height); 
     if($width>0 and $height>0){
     $imageinfo['mime']='image/svg+xml';
     }; //if($width>0 and $height>0){
     
 }
```

Comment: The use of the predefined variable `$_FILES` should be more highlighted in your answer. Could you add a section describing it ?

Answer (score -1):

```
pathinfo($_FILES['File']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION)
```

Use a built-in function whenever possible, and
Extract only the needed information (options = PATHINFO_EXTENSION)

Comment: keep in mind, that that check is not to be trusted. E.g. if the user did upload that file the user could easily change a file extension in many cases.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-

```
$extensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png","svg","gif");    
$file_ext       = strtolower(end(explode('.',$file['name'])));
if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== true){
    ...
    ...
}
```