# Why does PHP’s mime_content_type() function detect this SVG image as HTML?

Tags: php, image, svg, mime-types

I want to generate thumbnails of uploaded images other than SVG images, so my code goes (simplified):

```php
if (mime_content_type($uploaded) === 'image/svg+xml') {
    //
} else {
    createThumbs($uploaded);
}
```

However, for this uploaded image, `mime_content_type()` returns `text/html`. Why? And how can I fix this?

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 347.27 161.41"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#fe0000;}</style></defs><title>Log-BDS-driving-school_1</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><path class="cls-1" d="M62.72,1.54c10.77,0,16.6.72,21.1,2.46,7.14,2.77,11.1,8.31,11.1,15.28S91.4,30.88,84,33.13q15.17,3.38,15.17,16.62c0,8.72-5.61,15.49-15.17,18.36C79.31,69.45,73.6,70,61.73,70H39.85V1.54Zm1.65,26.67c8.46,0,11.54-1.74,11.54-6.77a5.85,5.85,0,0,0-4-5.95c-1.43-.41-3.3-.62-7.69-.62H58.87V28.21Zm1.21,28.41c5.72,0,7.58-.2,9.45-.92a7,7,0,0,0,4.4-7A6.91,6.91,0,0,0,74,41.54c-1.65-.51-3.74-.72-9.23-.72H58.87v15.8Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M164.5,1.54c14.29,0,22.42,1.54,29.13,5.54,10.22,6.05,15.83,16.21,15.83,28.62,0,13.64-6.81,24.62-18.58,30.26-6,2.77-14,4-26.38,4H143.4V1.54Zm4.18,54.37c7.14,0,11.54-1.13,14.73-3.8,3.74-3.18,5.94-9.13,5.94-16.41,0-7.9-2.53-14.16-7-17.13-3.08-2.05-7.25-3-13.63-3h-5.82V55.91Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M288.24,22.67c-.11-6.36-3.08-8.92-10.11-8.92-5.71,0-8.9,1.95-8.9,5.33a4.06,4.06,0,0,0,2.31,3.69c1.76.92,1.76.92,11.65,4.82s12.86,5.33,16.6,8.21A17.51,17.51,0,0,1,307,50.26c0,13-11.54,21.23-30,21.23-14.29,0-24-4.41-28.36-12.93-1.87-3.69-2.31-5.74-2.31-12.1h17.92c.77,8,4.62,11.28,13.08,11.28,6.16,0,9.89-2.05,9.89-5.64,0-2.05-1.1-3.59-3.63-4.82-1.87-1-1.87-1-12.31-5.23-15.83-6.36-21.54-11.9-21.54-21.13C249.77,8.1,260.88,0,278.35,0c13.19,0,22.2,4,25.72,11.18,1.65,3.28,2.09,5.74,2.09,11.49Z"/><rect class="cls-1" x="109.41" y="50.5" width="20" height="20"/><rect class="cls-1" x="216.41" y="50.5" width="20" height="20"/><path d="M6,85.05a14.59,14.59,0,0,1,5.57.7,4.5,4.5,0,0,1,2.93,4.32A3.76,3.76,0,0,1,11.66,94q4,1,4,4.7a5.32,5.32,0,0,1-4,5.19,20.43,20.43,0,0,1-5.89.52H0V85.05Zm.44,7.54c2.23,0,3-.49,3-1.92a1.66,1.66,0,0,0-1-1.68,7,7,0,0,0-2-.17H5v3.77Zm.32,8a6.28,6.28,0,0,0,2.49-.26,2,2,0,0,0,1.16-2,1.94,1.94,0,0,0-1.42-2,8,8,0,0,0-2.44-.2H5v4.47Z"/><path d="M22.94,90.62a5.3,5.3,0,0,1,.26,1.89c1.07-1.62,2-2.18,3.57-2.18a5.67,5.67,0,0,1,1.77.29V95.2a4,4,0,0,0-2.44-1.07,2.46,2.46,0,0,0-2.26,1.71,9.06,9.06,0,0,0-.44,3.48v5.08H18.47V93.55a8.88,8.88,0,0,0-.38-2.93Z"/><path d="M45.16,97.49c0,4.21-3.25,7.25-7.72,7.25s-7.77-3-7.77-7.34c0-4.09,3.31-7.14,7.75-7.14S45.16,93.32,45.16,97.49Zm-10.47,0c0,2.26,1.1,3.8,2.73,3.8s2.73-1.54,2.73-3.77-1.1-3.74-2.73-3.74S34.68,95.29,34.68,97.47Z"/><path d="M62.29,97.49c0,4.21-3.25,7.25-7.72,7.25s-7.77-3-7.77-7.34c0-4.09,3.31-7.14,7.75-7.14S62.29,93.32,62.29,97.49Zm-10.47,0c0,2.26,1.1,3.8,2.73,3.8s2.73-1.54,2.73-3.77-1.1-3.74-2.73-3.74S51.82,95.29,51.82,97.47Z"/><path d="M69.89,85.05V96.16l4.44-5.54h6L74.39,97l6.35,7.37H74.33L69.89,98.1v6.29H65V85.05Z"/><path d="M90.65,90.62V94h-3V104.4H82.76V94H80.65V90.62h2.12v-.41c0-2.23.35-3.34,1.33-4.23A5.25,5.25,0,0,1,88,84.7a17.75,17.75,0,0,1,3.28.35v3.48a12.84,12.84,0,0,0-2.29-.2c-.67,0-1.1.23-1.25.73a5.08,5.08,0,0,0-.12,1.57Z"/><path d="M98.13,87a2.45,2.45,0,0,1-2.76,2.41c-1.68,0-2.78-.93-2.78-2.35a2.55,2.55,0,0,1,2.84-2.44A2.44,2.44,0,0,1,98.13,87Zm-.29,3.63V104.4H92.91V90.62Z"/><path d="M105.36,98.6a3,3,0,0,0,5.37,1.42l4.47.14c-.84,3-3.39,4.58-7.16,4.58-4.58,0-7.54-2.81-7.54-7.16s3.07-7.31,7.63-7.31c4.38,0,7.22,2.87,7.22,7.31,0,.26,0,.61,0,1Zm5-3A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,108,93.55a2.39,2.39,0,0,0-2.55,2.06Z"/><path d="M122.93,85.05V104.4H118V85.05Z"/><path d="M140.36,85.05v15.11c0,3.08,0,3.19.38,4.24h-4.58c-.09-.41-.15-.64-.23-1.16a4.7,4.7,0,0,1-3.74,1.45c-3.89,0-6.58-3-6.58-7.22s2.61-7.14,6.24-7.14a4.74,4.74,0,0,1,3.6,1.42v-6.7Zm-9.75,12.44c0,2.12,1,3.51,2.44,3.51s2.44-1.39,2.44-3.45-1-3.54-2.44-3.54S130.61,95.41,130.61,97.49Z"/><path d="M157.26,85.05c3.77,0,5.92.44,7.69,1.57a9.92,9.92,0,0,1-.73,16.65c-1.6.78-3.68,1.13-7,1.13H151.7V85.05Zm1.1,15.37c1.89,0,3-.32,3.89-1.07a6.29,6.29,0,0,0,1.57-4.64c0-2.23-.67-4-1.86-4.84a6,6,0,0,0-3.6-.84h-1.54v11.4Z"/><path d="M176.38,90.62a5.3,5.3,0,0,1,.26,1.89c1.07-1.62,2-2.18,3.57-2.18a5.67,5.67,0,0,1,1.77.29V95.2a4,4,0,0,0-2.44-1.07,2.46,2.46,0,0,0-2.26,1.71,9.06,9.06,0,0,0-.44,3.48v5.08h-4.93V93.55a8.88,8.88,0,0,0-.38-2.93Z"/><path d="M189,87a2.45,2.45,0,0,1-2.76,2.41c-1.68,0-2.78-.93-2.78-2.35a2.55,2.55,0,0,1,2.84-2.44A2.44,2.44,0,0,1,189,87Zm-.29,3.63V104.4h-4.93V90.62Z"/><path d="M195.51,90.62l2.81,8.93,3-8.93h5.08l-5.6,13.78h-5l-5.51-13.78Z"/><path d="M213.18,87a2.45,2.45,0,0,1-2.76,2.41c-1.68,0-2.78-.93-2.78-2.35a2.55,2.55,0,0,1,2.84-2.44A2.44,2.44,0,0,1,213.18,87Zm-.29,3.63V104.4H208V90.62Z"/><path d="M220.74,90.62a3.86,3.86,0,0,1,.35,1.16A5.34,5.34,0,0,1,225,90.33a5.1,5.1,0,0,1,4.81,2.58c.41.81.49,1.59.49,3.77v7.72h-4.93V97.23a6.29,6.29,0,0,0-.2-2.15,1.6,1.6,0,0,0-1.62-1,1.91,1.91,0,0,0-1.83,1.1,5,5,0,0,0-.29,2.12v7.08h-4.93V95.64c0-3.22,0-3.51-.58-5Z"/><path d="M248,93.72h-2.44a3.52,3.52,0,0,1,.44,1.8,3.91,3.91,0,0,1-2.7,3.8c-1.07.43-1.39.49-4.18.7-.93.06-1.36.29-1.36.72a.58.58,0,0,0,.44.58,11.63,11.63,0,0,0,2.44.26,12.4,12.4,0,0,1,4.58.93,3.81,3.81,0,0,1,2.2,3.6c0,3-2.84,4.76-7.77,4.76-4.76,0-7.66-1.62-7.66-4.26,0-1.42.67-2.35,2.29-3.13a2.16,2.16,0,0,1-1-1.91,2.73,2.73,0,0,1,2.12-2.64,3.78,3.78,0,0,1-2-3.48c0-3.1,2.52-5.11,6.44-5.11a15.48,15.48,0,0,1,2.87.29H248Zm-11.66,12.65c0,.84,1.1,1.28,3.36,1.28s3.36-.44,3.36-1.28-1.07-1.28-3.34-1.28S236.32,105.5,236.32,106.37Zm1.42-11.25c0,1,.73,1.62,1.94,1.62s1.94-.61,1.94-1.62-.73-1.62-1.91-1.62S237.74,94.1,237.74,95.12Z"/><path d="M267,91c0-1.8-.81-2.52-2.67-2.52-1.51,0-2.35.55-2.35,1.51a1.16,1.16,0,0,0,.61,1,27.71,27.71,0,0,0,3.07,1.36c2.64,1.13,3.39,1.51,4.38,2.32a5.08,5.08,0,0,1,1.91,4.09c0,3.68-3,6-7.92,6-3.77,0-6.32-1.25-7.48-3.66a6.51,6.51,0,0,1-.61-3.42h4.73c.2,2.26,1.22,3.19,3.45,3.19,1.62,0,2.61-.58,2.61-1.59a1.48,1.48,0,0,0-1-1.36,26.38,26.38,0,0,0-3.25-1.48c-4.18-1.8-5.69-3.37-5.69-6,0-3.63,2.93-5.92,7.54-5.92,3.48,0,5.86,1.13,6.79,3.16A6.61,6.61,0,0,1,271.7,91Z"/><path d="M283.07,95.55a1.81,1.81,0,0,0-2-1.8c-1.6,0-2.55,1.42-2.55,3.8s.93,3.71,2.49,3.71c1.25,0,1.8-.61,2-2.18h4.73c-.12,3.66-2.52,5.66-6.82,5.66-4.55,0-7.46-2.81-7.46-7.22s3-7.25,7.54-7.25c4.09,0,6.56,1.91,6.73,5.28Z"/><path d="M295.51,85.05v6.7a5.46,5.46,0,0,1,4-1.42,4.9,4.9,0,0,1,4.21,1.89c.72,1,.9,1.86.9,4.26v7.92h-4.93V97.23a5.4,5.4,0,0,0-.23-2.09,1.73,1.73,0,0,0-1.71-1,2,2,0,0,0-1.89,1.13,5,5,0,0,0-.32,2.2v7h-4.93V85.05Z"/><path d="M322.54,97.49c0,4.21-3.25,7.25-7.72,7.25s-7.77-3-7.77-7.34c0-4.09,3.31-7.14,7.74-7.14S322.54,93.32,322.54,97.49Zm-10.47,0c0,2.26,1.1,3.8,2.73,3.8s2.73-1.54,2.73-3.77-1.1-3.74-2.73-3.74S312.06,95.29,312.06,97.47Z"/><path d="M339.67,97.49c0,4.21-3.25,7.25-7.72,7.25s-7.77-3-7.77-7.34c0-4.09,3.31-7.14,7.74-7.14S339.67,93.32,339.67,97.49Zm-10.47,0c0,2.26,1.1,3.8,2.73,3.8s2.73-1.54,2.73-3.77-1.1-3.74-2.73-3.74S329.2,95.29,329.2,97.47Z"/><path d="M347.27,85.05V104.4h-4.93V85.05Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M45.36,144.85c0,10.34-4.95,16.56-13.18,16.56S19,155.24,19,144.6c0-10,5-16.32,13.23-16.32S45.36,134.51,45.36,144.85ZM28.85,137a19.3,19.3,0,0,0-1.47,7.74,19.62,19.62,0,0,0,1.47,7.94,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,3.33,2.2,3.5,3.5,0,0,0,3.28-2.2,19,19,0,0,0,1.47-7.84,18.55,18.55,0,0,0-1.47-7.79,3.58,3.58,0,0,0-3.33-2.25A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,28.85,137Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M50.12,137.7c0-5.59,4.9-9.41,12.1-9.41s12.1,3.72,12.1,9.31a6.33,6.33,0,0,1-3.87,6.32c2.94,1.22,4.51,3.72,4.51,7.3,0,6.17-5,10.19-12.74,10.19s-12.74-4-12.74-10.09c0-3.53,1.57-6.12,4.51-7.4A6.23,6.23,0,0,1,50.12,137.7Zm7.79,13.38c0,2.3,1.71,3.82,4.31,3.82s4.31-1.52,4.31-3.87-1.62-3.87-4.26-3.87S57.91,148.67,57.91,151.07Zm.64-13.23c0,2,1.42,3.28,3.67,3.28s3.67-1.27,3.67-3.28a3.33,3.33,0,0,0-3.63-3.33C60,134.51,58.54,135.83,58.54,137.84Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M105.48,128.92v5.34L89.27,160.77H80l15.24-24.84H80.79v-7Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M123.12,139c0-2.84.15-3.63.88-5.19,1.71-3.48,5.73-5.54,10.88-5.54,6.86,0,11.27,3.43,11.27,8.72,0,4.51-3.14,8.72-12.49,16.76H146.3v7H122.63v-5.83c1.37-1.42,4.95-5.15,10.63-11.17,3.38-3.53,4-4.46,4-6.12s-1.18-2.79-3.09-2.79c-2.4,0-3.48,1.22-3.77,4.17Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M174.92,128.92l-.49,6.71H162.52l-.78,3.53a11.53,11.53,0,0,1,3.92-.59c6.81,0,11.37,4.31,11.37,10.78a12.1,12.1,0,0,1-4.07,9.21,13.6,13.6,0,0,1-8.92,2.84c-4.26,0-7.69-1.32-9.8-3.87-1.52-1.71-2.11-3.48-2.25-6.57h7.94c.39,2.6,1.67,3.72,4.12,3.72,2.84,0,4.56-1.91,4.56-5s-1.62-4.75-4.26-4.75c-1.91,0-2.89.54-4.75,2.5l-7-.93,3.63-17.59Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M185.26,161.26c5.49-6.12,5.68-6.37,8.33-9.7h-.73c-6.27,0-10.93-4.75-10.93-11.17,0-7.15,5.19-12.1,12.69-12.1s12.69,4.95,12.69,12.15c0,4.31-2,8.77-5.93,13.67-1.37,1.67-2.5,2.89-6.66,7.15Zm5.1-21.07c0,3.09,1.71,5.14,4.26,5.14s4.26-2.06,4.26-5.14-1.71-5.19-4.21-5.19S190.35,137.06,190.35,140.19Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M235,128.92l-.49,6.71H222.59l-.78,3.53a11.53,11.53,0,0,1,3.92-.59c6.81,0,11.37,4.31,11.37,10.78a12.1,12.1,0,0,1-4.07,9.21,13.6,13.6,0,0,1-8.92,2.84c-4.26,0-7.69-1.32-9.8-3.87-1.52-1.71-2.11-3.48-2.25-6.57H220c.39,2.6,1.67,3.72,4.12,3.72,2.84,0,4.56-1.91,4.56-5s-1.62-4.75-4.26-4.75c-1.91,0-2.89.54-4.75,2.5l-7-.93,3.63-17.59Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M245.33,161.26c5.49-6.12,5.68-6.37,8.33-9.7h-.73c-6.27,0-10.93-4.75-10.93-11.17,0-7.15,5.19-12.1,12.69-12.1s12.69,4.95,12.69,12.15c0,4.31-2,8.77-5.93,13.67-1.37,1.67-2.5,2.89-6.66,7.15Zm5.1-21.07c0,3.09,1.71,5.14,4.26,5.14s4.26-2.06,4.26-5.14-1.71-5.19-4.21-5.19S250.42,137.06,250.42,140.19Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M298,128.92v5.34l-16.22,26.51h-9.31l15.24-24.84h-14.4v-7Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M327.94,144.85c0,10.34-4.95,16.56-13.18,16.56s-13.23-6.17-13.23-16.81c0-10,5-16.32,13.23-16.32S327.94,134.51,327.94,144.85ZM311.43,137a19.3,19.3,0,0,0-1.47,7.74,19.62,19.62,0,0,0,1.47,7.94,3.56,3.56,0,0,0,3.33,2.2,3.5,3.5,0,0,0,3.28-2.2,19,19,0,0,0,1.47-7.84,18.53,18.53,0,0,0-1.47-7.79,3.58,3.58,0,0,0-3.33-2.25A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,311.43,137Z"/></g></g></svg>
```

PHP version: PHP 5.6.31-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263957/why-is-mime-content-type-deprecated-in-php?rq=1

Comment: @jorgonor. Apparently it's not actually depricated. That was [a documentation mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676272/209139).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is missing `<xml>` tag. Prepend it with something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` line and it should work.